# WLST : update JTA Transaction timeout

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, wlst

I want to increase the JTA Transaction Timeout value of WLS, but I got this error:

```
wls:/mydomain/edit !> cd('/JTA/myDomain')
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in ?
  File "<iostream>", line 164, in cd
  File "<iostream>", line 552, in raiseWLSTException
WLSTException: Error cding to the MBean
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is case sensitive. Use cd('/JTA/mydomain') instead of cd('/JTA/myDomain')

Comment: well, the real name is of the domain is tdk_admin

Comment: your wlst prompt says taht the domain name is mydomain.

Comment: true, folder name tdk_admin, but domain name mydomain

Comment: as a best practice, folder name and domain name should always be the same.